# Pandas calculate rolling count of consecutive values within tolerance

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a list of requests counts to a website for consecutive days. I want to calculate the number of days the current day's request count is within some tolerance (% of the current day's count).

Synthetic example:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({'req': {0: 15, 1: 16, 2: 14, 3: 15, 4: 16, 5: 16, 6: 17, 7: 30, 8: 31, 9: 35, 10: 32, 11: 35, 12: 34, 13: 33, 14: 37}, 'lo': {0: 13.5, 1: 14.4, 2: 12.6, 3: 13.5, 4: 14.4, 5: 14.4, 6: 15.3, 7: 27.0, 8: 27.9, 9: 31.5, 10: 28.8, 11: 31.5, 12: 30.6, 13: 29.7, 14: 33.3}, 'hi': {0: 16.5, 1: 17.6, 2: 15.4, 3: 16.5, 4: 17.6, 5: 17.6, 6: 18.7, 7: 33.0, 8: 34.1, 9: 38.5, 10: 35.2, 11: 38.5, 12: 37.4, 13: 36.3, 14: 40.7}, 'con10': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 3, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 0, 8: 1, 9: 0, 10: 3, 11: 2, 12: 4, 13: 6, 14: 0}})
    req    lo    hi  con10
0    15  13.5  16.5      0
1    16  14.4  17.6      1
2    14  12.6  15.4      0
3    15  13.5  16.5      3
4    16  14.4  17.6      1
5    16  14.4  17.6      2
6    17  15.3  18.7      2
7    30  27.0  33.0      0
8    31  27.9  34.1      1
9    35  31.5  38.5      0
10   32  28.8  35.2      3
11   35  31.5  38.5      2
12   34  30.6  37.4      4
13   33  29.7  36.3      6
14   37  33.3  40.7      0
```

Above:

- `req` is the number of requests for that day,
- `lo` and `hi` is the tolerance band for that day and
- `con10` is the number of consecutive days that precede this day where the number of requests is within the given tolerance (10% in this case).

Any pointers regarding how I would calculate `con` for a given tolerance (or more generally a list of tolerances, i.e. `con05`, `con07`, `con10` for 5/7/10% respectively)?

Comment: You may want to show more detail about this .

Comment: @BENY Sure, what kind of details do you think would be useful for me to add?

Comment: Just why row 1 16 the con10 equal to 1

Comment: @BENY Row 1 has req=16, so the -+10% band is lo-hi=14.4-17.6. con10=1 because that many consecutive rows which precede row 1 fall within that band (i.e. row 0 has value 15 which falls between 14.4-17.6). Let me know if that makes it clearer.

Comment: What about idx 3 with req=15, why it's not 3 in `con10`?

Comment: Thanks @CainãMaxCouto-Silva - that was an error on my part, I've corrected the post.

Comment: Your last value should be 0 as well, right!?

Comment: @CainãMaxCouto-Silva Correct, I've updated that one as well. Thanks for catching these two!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:**

Here's a way to get it done (taking the last previous rows):

```py
def last_within_range(df, target_col='req', tolerance=10):
    
    df = df.copy()
    s = pd.Series(dtype=int, index=df.index)
    
    # Get low and high tolerance
    df['lo'] = df[target_col] - df[target_col] * tolerance/100
    df['hi'] = df[target_col] + df[target_col] * tolerance/100
    
    # Find how many last rows the current value from `req` is within the desired range  
    for idx in df.index[1:]:
        past_idx = df.index[:df.index.get_loc(idx)]
        req = df.loc[idx, 'req']
        # Get bool values and identify groups to get the last one
        values = (req >= df.loc[past_idx, 'lo']) & (req <= df.loc[past_idx, 'hi'])
        grps = (values != values.shift()).cumsum()
        # If the last group is True, then get its sum
        s[idx] = grps.eq(grps.iloc[-1]).sum() if values.iloc[-1] == True else 0
        
    return df.assign(**{f'con{tolerance}': s})

last_within_range(df, tolerance=10)
```

Output:

```
    req    lo    hi  con10
0    15  13.5  16.5      0
1    16  14.4  17.6      1
2    14  12.6  15.4      0
3    15  13.5  16.5      3
4    16  14.4  17.6      1
5    16  14.4  17.6      2
6    17  15.3  18.7      2
7    30  27.0  33.0      0
8    31  27.9  34.1      1
9    35  31.5  38.5      0
10   32  28.8  35.2      3
11   35  31.5  38.5      2
12   34  30.6  37.4      4
13   33  29.7  36.3      6
14   37  33.3  40.7      0
```

It uses a loop, though :(

---

**Original Answer:**

You can use a function to get calcule `lo` and `hi`, then use them within a loop through the indexes. Take a look at the following function:

```py
def last_within_range(df, target_col='req', tolerance=10):
    
    df = df.copy()
    s = pd.Series(dtype=int, index=df.index)
    
    # Get low and high tolerance
    df['lo'] = df[target_col] - df[target_col] * tolerance/100
    df['hi'] = df[target_col] + df[target_col] * tolerance/100
    
    # Find how many last rows the current value from `req` is within the desired range  
    for idx in df.index:
        past_idx = df.index[:df.index.get_loc(idx)]
        req = df.loc[idx, 'req']
        s[idx] = (
            ((req >= df.loc[past_idx, 'lo']) & (req <= df.loc[past_idx, 'hi'])).sum()
        )
        
    return s # df.assign(**{f'con{tolerance}': s})
```

where it returns a `Series` as output. So, for example:

```py
df['con5'] = last_within_range(df, tolerance=5)
df['con7'] = last_within_range(df, tolerance=7)
df['con10'] = last_within_range(df, tolerance=10)
```

```
    req  con5  con7  con10
0    15     0     0      0
1    16     0     1      1
2    14     0     1      1
3    15     1     2      3
4    16     1     3      3
5    16     2     4      4
6    17     0     3      3
7    30     0     0      0
8    31     1     1      1
9    35     0     0      0
10   32     1     2      3
11   35     1     1      2
12   34     2     3      4
13   33     2     5      6
14   37     0     2      3
```

---

Note that it **does not** return how many **consecutive** previous rows are within the expected range, but it returns how many of the previous rows obeys your criteria.

Also, if you want to see the output alongside the calculated `lo` and `hi`, you run return a dataframe instead by replacing the return statement to `df.assign(**{f'con{tolerance}': s})` rather than `s`.

Comment: Thanks! The consecutive requirement is important though. Also, since the data volume is not insignificant, is there a way to avoid the python looping part (`for idx in df.index:`), i.e. do it with pandas only?

Comment: I don't think so. Although pandas provides a `rolling`, you're not looking for a specific window approach. You're gonna need to analyze all the previous rows for each row, then identify if there's a group of last consecutive `True`s... It's possible to adapt this code for achieving it (if you're interested), though.

Comment: I've updated the question. Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out a way with pandas only, without loop, but it works. Let me know if you have any doubts. Best!